# Can Chrome extensions read browser history across all devices?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-history

I've installed a Chrome extension on my Desktop computer(Windows 10). It has permission to read my browser(Chrome) history which is synced across all devices(namely, my Android phone and my desktop). But the extension itself is not synced and is only installed on my Desktop.

So, can the extension read the browser(Chrome) history from my phone?

Comment: No, extensions can only access the current browser where they run.

Comment: Please make more obvious how this is a programming question, in order to avoid being closed for being off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

No, extensions can only read the history of yours current browser where they are installed

Answer (score 0):

Strictly phrased no, chrome cannot read browser history on a device it is not running on.
But if the history it can read (with given permissions) happens to be identical to all other histories, then you won't know the difference.